# How to use Edittext In GroupView of ExpandableListView, edittext cannot get focused

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have a `ExpandableListView` and each `groupView` has a `EditText`.
If I set the edittext `android:focusable=true` then the groupView item cannot get focused, which means the group can't be expanded. If I set the ediitext `android:focusable=false`, then the edittext cannot get focused while de groupView can be expanded. I have tried to add code 
`sheetListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);`
But it seems no use for me.

Here is the GroupView layout file:`R.layout.item_receiving_scan_box`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="7"
        android:id="@+id/edittext_receiving_scan_box_count_count"
        android:text="20"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_receiving_scan_box_scan_count"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_receiving_scan_box_scan_count"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_receiving_scan_box_scan_count" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my ExpandableListViewAdapter getGroupView code

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_receiving_scan_box, null);
    TextView matCode = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_receiving_scan_box_mat_code);
    TextView boxCount = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_receiving_scan_box_count);
    matCode.setText(matCode.getText()+mReceivingBoxes.get(groupPosition).get("matCode"));
    boxCount.setText(boxCount.getText()+mReceivingBoxes.get(groupPosition).get("boxCount"));
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: You need to set `setFocusable="true"` when your groupView expanded.

Answer (score 0):

try below line in your root layout :-

```
before_descendent
```

in your xml

Comment: root layout, you mean the layout of the groupview or the layout of the actvity?